# Как корректно подключить классы между собой

Tags: c++, qt, header

Есть два класса "connection" и "modbus" хедер класса modbus подключается в другой класс без проблем, но если привязать при этом и обратную связь начинает ругаться на ошибки "does not a type". Как корректно связать между собой классы с двунаправленной связью, что бы можно было без проблем объявлять глобальные переменные и там и там.

Comment: Глобальные переменные - это зло.

Comment: что бы победить зло, нужно думать как зло :)

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration и указатели или ссылки. Обращения к методам спрятать в файлы реализации.

```
// A.h
#pragma once
class B;

class A {
    B *another;
public:
    A(B *b);
};

//A.cpp
#include "B.h"

A::A(B *b)
    : another(b)
{
}

// B.h
#pragma once
class A;

class B {
    A *another;
public:
    B(A *a);
};

//B.cpp
#include "A.h"

B::B(A *a)
    : another(a)
{
}
```